# Upload file via POST call with C#, RestSharp, Redmine API

Tags: c#, post, upload, redmine, restsharp

I'm developing a C# app that uses Redmine REST API, it uses RestSharp Client. All other REST calls I make work fine but I cannot find a way to upload attachments. I've widely searched the web and tried many solutions but nothing worked.
Redmine documentiation on attachments: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Attaching-files
The code actually looks like:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://myclient/redmine/");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("myuser", "mypsw");
var request2 = new RestRequest("uploads.json", Method.POST);
request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
request2.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
byte[] dataToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(AddIssue.attach.Text);
request2.AddBody(dataToSend);
IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request2);
resultbox.Text = response2.Content;
```

If I execute it above nothing happens and the response is empty. If I remove line 7 (the AddBody), it actually works but of course nothing is uploaded, JSON response:
{
    "upload": {
        "token": "11."
    }
}

So actually, the real question is what to punt in AddBody() to send the file as  application/octet-stream. Since RestSharp also has a request.AddFile() method, I tried it too in different ways but nothing...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: No one? Everything works fine if I use POSTMAN (Chrome plugin) and select a file under "form-data"...

Comment: I'm having similar issues with Dropbox - which requires the entire request body to be the byte array (while `AddFile()` creates a multi-part form). [Upload to dropbox using Restsharp PCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577598/upload-to-dropbox-using-restsharp-pcl) may provide some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, it sounds like Redmine might have requirements similar to Dropbox. Here is the solution that worked for me (based on the question *[Upload to dropbox using Restsharp PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577598/1058872)*):

```
public static void UploadFileToDropbox(string filePath)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/");
    IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("files_put/auto/{path}", Method.PUT);

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString());

    request.AddUrlSegment("path", string.Format("Public/{0}", fileInfo.Name));

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var body = new Parameter
    {
        Name = "file",
        Value = data,
        Type = ParameterType.RequestBody,
    };
    request.Parameters.Add(body);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Also [published as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/cmshawns/49537d4d53d8dd96bed4).

I know this isn't your exact situation, but hopefully it gives you some ideas.